# Error in Insert Data using Php and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with file upload and user name exits checking conditions.
What im facing it the data are not getting insert in mysql db. file as been successfully saved in given path. kindly help me on this im wasted already 2days with that i tried a lot myself.

form.php

```html
<table style="text-align:right">
    <form id="add" method="POST" action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <tr>
            <h4 class='bg-info'>
                <br/> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Become a Member of jobportal and find the right job. Create your Profile now, Free!<br/><br/>
            </h4>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td> * Mandatory Fields  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <td>Enter Your Email-ID: *</td>
            <td><input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email ID" type="textfield" name="email"required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Choose password *</td>
            <td><input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter Your Password" type="password" name="password"required/></td>
        </tr>
            <td>Re-Enter Your password *</td>
            <td><input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter Your Password" type="password" name="repassword"required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Please Enter Your Full Name:</td>
            <td> <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter Full Name" type="textfield" name="name"required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Your Current Location: *<td>
            <select class="form-control input-sm" required name="location">
                <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Select location *</option>
                <option>Andhra Pradesh</option>
                <option>Arunachal Pradesh</option>
                <option>Assam</option>
                <option>Bihar</option>
                <option>Chhattisgarh</option>
                <option>Goa</option>
                <option>Gujarat</option>
                <option>Haryana</option>
                <option>Himachal Pradesh</option>
                <option>Jammu and Kashmir</option>
                <option>Jharkhand</option>
                <option>Karnataka</option>
                <option>Kerala</option>
                <option>Madhya Pradesh</option>
                <option>Maharashtra</option>
                <option>Maharashtra</option>
                <option>Manipur</option>
                <option>Meghalaya</option>
                <option>Mizoram</option>
                <option>Nagaland</option>
                <option>Odisha</option>
                <option>Punjab</option>
                <option>Rajasthan</option>
                <option>Sikkim</option>
                <option>Tamil Nadu</option>
                <option>Telangana</option>
                <option>Tripura</option>
                <option>Uttar Pradesh</option>
                <option>Uttarakhand</option>
                <option>West Bengal</option>
            </select></td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Your Mobile Number: *</td>
            <td><input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="mobile number" type="textfield" name="mobilenumber" required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Experience:</td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" required name="experience">
                    <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Select Experience</option>
                    <option>Fresher</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Key Skill: *</td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter Your Skill" type="textfield" name="keyskill"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Please Select your PG Degree</td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" required name="degree">
                    <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Select Degree</option>
                    <option>B.sc</option>
                    <option>B.E</option>
                    <option>B.Com</option>
                    <option>others</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Please Select Higher Studies:</td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" required name="hsc">
                    <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Select Higher Studies</option>
                    <option>HSC</option>
                    <option>Diploma</option>
                    <option>ITI</option>
                    <option>others</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Please Select your Gender: *</td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" required name="gender">
                    <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Select</option>
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                    <option>others</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Upload your Resume :</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="filep"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td>by clicking register u accepting our terms and condtions. click here !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="add" value="Register With JobPortal">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

action.php

```php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo 'connected';
}
if (isset($_POST['add']) ) {
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
        $email = addslashes ($_POST['email']);
    } else {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = md5 ($_POST['password']);
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $mobilenumber = $_POST['mobilenumber'];
    $experience = $_POST['experience'];
    $keyskill  = $_POST['keyskill'];
    $degree = $_POST['degree'];
    $hsc = $_POST['hsc'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $resume = $_FILES['filep']['name'];
    $folder = "C:/wamp/www/userlogin/pic/";
    $name="SELECT emailid FROM userregistration WHERE emailid='$email'";
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'login');
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $name);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0) {
       echo "Username already exists";
    } else {
        echo"data entered done";
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filep"]["tmp_name"], $folder . $_FILES["filep"]["name"])) {
        echo "images moved sus";
    } else {
        echo "not done";
    }

    echo "<p align=center>File ".$_FILES["filep"]["name"]."loaded...";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO userregistration "
        . "(email, password, name, location, mobilenumber, experience, keyskill, degree, hsc, gender, resume)"
        . "VALUES('$email', '$password', '$name', '$location', '$mobilenumber', '$experience', '$keyskill',
        '$degree', '$hsc', '$gender', '$resume')";
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'login');
    $retval = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (!$retval) {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Entered data successfully\n";
    echo'<a href="index.php"> insert more data </a>';
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

What I exactly need is: I want to upload form data with the file url into database and need to check email id or name already exits.

I only get error in `$sql = "insert into"` portion other than else working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try without wrapping ..and see results any error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Could not enter data:    im getting this error ., i thing the loop going upto last if condition  @Mureinik

Comment: Use prepared statements... or at least escape the request data before inserting it into the database. Your code is open to `sql injections`.

Comment: This is not related to your question. which version of php are you using? `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: php 5.5.12 version im using

Comment: Please show the error you are getting.

Comment: Print the query and manually fire it on database...check weather the data get inserted or not

Comment: how to avoid sql injections @Jite

Comment: Could not enter data: im getting this error ., i thing the loop going upto last if condition @Jite

Comment: First and easiest step is to use [`prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Or at the very least, escaping the input from user.

Comment: i will try prepared statements @Jite

Answer (score 0):

### Errors

1. Missing database name

   ```
   mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
   ```
2. And error in `$sql` query

So final well-From code is

```
<?php
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");;//missing database

    if (! $con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else{
        echo 'connected';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
        if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
        {
            $email = addslashes ($_POST['email']);
        }
        else
        {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
        }
        $email  = $_POST['email'];
        $password  = md5 ($_POST['password']);
        $name    = $_POST['name'];
        $location = $_POST['location'];
        $mobilenumber = $_POST['mobilenumber'];
        $experience  = $_POST['experience'];
        $keyskill    = $_POST['keyskill'];
        $degree      = $_POST['degree'];
        $hsc     = $_POST['hsc'];
        $gender  = $_POST['gender'];
        $resume = $_FILES['filep']['name'];
        $folder = "C:/wamp/www/userlogin/pic/";

        $query001="SELECT emailid FROM userregistration WHERE emailid='$email'";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query001);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0){

            echo "Username already exists";
        }
        else
        {
            echo"data entered done";
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filep"]["tmp_name"], $folder . $_FILES["filep"]["name"]))
            {
                echo "images moved sus";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "not done";
            }

            echo "<p align=center>File ".$_FILES["filep"]["name"]."loaded...";

            $sql = "INSERT INTO userregistration (email, password, name, location, mobilenumber, experience, keyskill,
    degree, hsc, gender, resume) VALUES('$email','$password','$name','$location','$mobilenumber','$experience','$keyskill','$degree','$hsc','$gender','$resume')";
            $retval = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            if(!$retval )
            {
                die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Entered data successfully\n";
                echo'<a href="index.php"> insert more data </a>';
                mysqli_close($con);
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

and be aware with [MySQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

simply you can use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#refsect1-mysqli.real-escape-string-description)

Example

```
$name   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

> Tip from(Comment)
>   You have $name declared twice in your code - rename the $name select statement. (`$name = $_POST['name'];` and also `$name="SELECT emailid FROM userregistration WHERE emailid='$email'";` ) –  [Jesse C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891259/jesse-c)

Comment: let me try this @abdulla

Comment: username exits checking correctly whether already exits shows already exits else username entered successfully and file also moved to the path successfully and finally comes to $sql portion throws Could not enter data:... no other errors are getting

Comment: where i need to use  mysqli_real_escape_string()  in my code??

Comment: like this `$name   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);` each and every POST methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83832/discussion-between-user3427706-and-abdulla).

Comment: You have $name declared twice in your code - rename the $name select statement. ($name    = $_POST['name']; and also $name="SELECT emailid FROM userregistration WHERE emailid='$email'"; )

Comment: i renamed the both but same result., everything else was fine table name ect but i think some sql injuction error

Comment: So that use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 0):

echo your sql query before
`mysqli_select_db($con, 'login');`
and execute it in your Mysql phpmyadmin...

I guess there is some problem in your query formation, spacing between words or something.